# Classification of biclosed monoidal structures on the $2$-category of $2$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories

[This paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82322397.pdf) proves that the category of small categories and functors between them admits exactly two monoidal biclosed categories: the cartesian tensor product and the funny tensor product.

Is there a similar classification for monoidal biclosed $2$-category structures on the $2$-category of $2$-categories, $2$-functors, and $2$-transformations? In particular, are the Cartesian, funny, and Gray tensor products the unique such monoidal structures?

Comment: Crossposted: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229441/classification-of-biclosed-monoidal-structures-on-the-2-category-of-2-catego)

Comment: I'm not sure which version of the Gray tensor product you had in mind, but the pseudo Gray tensor product may be equivalent to the cartesian product for you, depending on how strictly you're working. The lax Gray tensor product of 2-categories comes in 4 variants when you conjugate by the 4 automorphsms of $2Cat$ (there would be 8 when you take into account the possibility of changing $A \otimes B$ to $B \otimes A$, but that ends up coinciding with conjugating by $op$).

Comment: I think the funny tensor product also comes in a few variants: given 2-categories $A,B$, the lax Gray tensor product of $\omega$-categories should give a 4-category $A \otimes B$. You can delete the noninvertible 4-cells, and invert the 3-cells, or you can delete both the noninvertible 3-cells and the non-invertible 4-cells, giving 2 different levels of "funniness". I suppose both of these can also be mixed and matched with treating the 2-cells in the "lax" or "pseudo" way. Then there's still automorphisms to conjugate by...

Comment: But given the results of Foltz-Lair-Kelly (and assuming the above all makes sense), it may be reasonable to guess that there are no monoidal biclosed structures on $2Cat$ other than the above.